# Help Finding Loop Invariant From For Loop

Tags: algorithms, loop-invariants, correctness-proof

I have created the algorithm below...

```
        String A = v[0];
        int val = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < v.length; i++) {
            if (val == 0) {
                A = v[i];
                val++;
            } else if (v[i].equals(A))
                val++;
            else
                val--;
        }
```

The goal of the algorithm is to find the item that occurs in more than half the array.

Let v = {"one", "two", "one", "three", "one", "two", "two", "one", "one"}

The string "one" occurs 5 out of 9 times.  So, at the end of the loop, the String A will be equal to "one".

I'm lost as to how to derive a loop invariant from this.  Could someone provide me with some direction?

Comment: What is the goal of this loop, in words?

Comment: I can't see how the algorithm does what you claim it does.

Comment: what if no such string exists as in `{"one","two","three"}`

Comment: @miracle173 I think that in that case, the result is undefined. In other words, it's allowed to be anything.

Comment: yes, if nothing occurs more than half the time, it is undefined.

Comment: so if there is an element in the array that occurs more than half the array the program will find it (we hope). I think you should add this assumption to your description

Comment: you say you have created the algorithm. Can you tell me why this algorithm will succeed on an array that satisfy the assumption? or do you mean that hou have read this algorithm and written the program and don't know why it succeeds?

Answer (score 3):

See this [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487018). You should provide reference for an algorithm when you did not write it, at least explain how you came up with it if you "created" it.

Terminology: this question is about finding the **majority element** of an array.

The invariant at step $i$ is:

- `A` occurs at least in `val` cells of `v[0..i]`
- The remaining `(i + 1 - val)` cells can be discarded without changing the majority element.

The algorithm is easy to accept as correct when you understand that if you remove two different elements of the array, then it keeps its majority element.